# Navigation ViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Please tell me which `ViewController`s can be placed inside `UINavigationViewContoller`?

I.e. can I make a `UINavigationViewController` the root view for `UITableViewController` or `UITabViewController`?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> initWithRootViewController:
>
> Initializes and returns a newly
>   created navigation controller.
>
> - (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController
>     *)rootViewController Parameters
>
> *rootViewController*
>
> The view controller that resides at the bottom of the navigation stack.
>   This object cannot be an instance of
>   the UITabBarController class.

So anything but an UITabBarController is fine

Comment: i was not clear when i went through the apple doc., ll u please tel me, is it restriction to make UITabViewController as root view to UINavigationViewController or is it restriction to make UINavigationViewController as root view for UITabViewController?

Comment: Again: You CANNOT have the UITabViewController as the root view to UINavigationController. UITabViewController CAN have UINavigationController as one of its views.